# What do I get if I declare an array without a size in global scope?

Tags: c, arrays, int, global-variables

In [one of the answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5163/38214) in [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/38214), I saw this code (ungolfed version):

```
s[],t;

main(c){
    for(scanf("%*d "); ~(c=getchar()); s[t++]=c)
        putchar(s[t]);
}
```

I think that the above program exhibits UB (but who cares in code golf?). But the thing that I don't understand is the `s[]` in global scope. I know that when the type of a global variable isn't specified, it defaults to `int`. I created a small program which surprisingly compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int s[];
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello!");
}
```

though it emits one warning:

```
prog.c:23:5: warning: array 's' assumed to have one element [enabled by default]
 int s[];
     ^
```

- What is `s` in the above program? Is it an `int*` or something else?
- Will this be useful anywhere?

Comment: `s` is an array of `int` with an implementation defined number of elements?

Comment: @alk , So, an implementation allocates some size for `s`?

Comment: Probably `0` or `1`?

Comment: @alk , I don't know. I can't use the `sizeof` operator to check it either(`error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'int[]'`) :-(

Comment: gcc assumes `s[]` to be `s[1]`. And gcc returns `4` for `sizeof s`.

Comment: see 6.9.2 External object definitions

Comment: Yes, the *implicitiy initialiser*! Why not make this an answer! @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @alk , "_And gcc returns `4` for `sizeof s`_" -- How did you test that? It gives an error for me (see my previous comment)

Comment: I compiled with symbols, ran gdb on `a.out`, did `b main`, `r` and then typed `p sizeof s`.

Comment: However the C11 Draft allows both  `sizeof s` to work or not.

Comment: I used gcc 4.7.2. But you are correct, although gdb evaluates `sizeof s`, gcc refused to compile it.

Comment: So to formally correct my comment stating "*gcc returns 4*": IT should read "*gdb returns 4*".

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , Please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is `s` in the above program? Is it an int* or something else?

`s` is an incomplete type. That's why you cannot `sizeof` it. As @BLUEPIXY suggests, it's initialized with zero because it's declared in global scope making a "tentative definition".

> `int i[];`
>   the array i still has incomplete type, the implicit initializer causes it to have one element, which is set to
>   zero on program startup.

Now,

> Will this be useful anywhere?

It's pretty useless if you're just using `s[0]` because at that point you go for `s;` directly. But, if you need an array with a certain size and you don't care about UBs, it's "okay".

Comment: But it isn't a "*member of structure*".

Comment: What do you mean, @alk? `s` is an incomplete type which is supposed to be used as a flexible array member. Other uses have no meaning.

Comment: I mean that as `s` isn't a "*member of a structure*" the appendix cited does not apply. Moreover following the C11 Draft 6.9.2/5 (as already mentioned by @BLUEPIXY): As `s` is of incomplete type **and** in global scope it gets implicilty initialised with `... = {0}`. So it ends up as `int[1]` with `s[0]` being equal to `0`.

Comment: I see, @alk. But, to the question "why is it an incomplete type", the answer is that's supposed to be a flexible array member. I'll update to clarify.